# Error while running the minitest, expecting <"admin/dashboard"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing

I have a failure while testing this code...
The error stated is "**expecting <"admin/dashboard"> but rendering with <[]>**"

The integration test page code snippet is

```
require 'test_helper'
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @admin = admins(:admn)
  end

  test "admin dashboard link" do
    get login_admin_path
    post login_admin_path, params: { session: { username: @admin.username,
                                          password: 'Ha66y@Air' } }        

    get admin_dashboard_path
    assert_template 'admin/dashboard'
 end
end
```

The code snippet in route.rb is

```
get '/admin/dashboard', to: 'admin#dashboard'
```

The code snippet in the login controller is

```
def create
    admin = Admin.find_by(username: params[:session][:username])
    if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # render 'admin/dashboard'
      log_in admin
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(admin) : forget(admin)

      redirect_to admin_dashboard_path


    else
      render 'login/admin'
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    end

  end
```

Code snippet in the admin controller is

```
def dashboard
    redirect_to root_url unless logged_in?
    @admin = current_user
  end
```

The code snippet for the admins.yml is

```
admn:
  username: "adminm"
  password_digest: <%= Admin.digest('admin') %>
```

The app ran successfully in the server. However the error occurs while running the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `redirect_to admin_dashboard_path` does not render a template, it renders a redirection command; an HTTP 302. The browser then immediately fetches the specified page, which is why the manual test passed. Try `assert_redirected_to`.

Comment: and now, the error given below is given
SiteLayoutTest#test_admin_dashboard_link [/home/levi/Documents/workspace/emportal/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:23]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.comadmin/dashboard> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/>.
Expected "http://www.example.comadmin/dashboard" to be === "http://www.example.com/".